# Attaching event listeners to an android UI componenet?

Tags: java, android

android 3.0 API Level 11

How do I attach an onTouch Event to the button?

TestDebugingActivity.java

```
package com.example.debuggingTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.*;

public class TestDebugingActivity extends Activity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this);


    setContentView(R.layout.linear);
  }


}
```

linear.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Firstname:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Lastname:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="E-mail:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Gender:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />





<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="224dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Male:" />


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Female:" />

</RadioGroup>







<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Register" />
```

Comment: add this line  setContentView(R.layout.linear); after  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tv.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this);` is invalid currently because your `this` is not an `OnTouchListener` and it does not implement the `OnTouchListener` interface either.

There are multiple ways this can be solved. An easy way (not necessarily best) is to have your activity implement OnTouchListener. To do that, you'll need to declare it and you'll need to add a single method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false; // (false: let the event bubble up; true: you handled it)
}
```

Comment: Additionally, as @Samir says, you need to change the ordering of setting your content view. You cannot find your TextView `tv` until it exists, which is not before you set the view.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a new anonymous class of the type OnTouchListener, like this:

```
tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        //handle touch here
        return true; //if handled
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true; 
    )
});
```